# Pull azure container registry image in kubernetes helm

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-container-registry

I'm working on a project using Helm-kubernetes and azure kubernetes service, in which I'm trying to use a simple node image which I have been pushed on azure container registry inside my helm chart but it returns `ImagePullBackOff` error.

Here are some details:

**My `Dockerfile`:**

```
FROM node:8

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app


COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 32000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**My `helm_chart/values.yaml`:**

```
replicaCount: 1

image:
  registry: helmcr.azurecr.io
  repository: helloworldtest
  tag: 0.7
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

service:
  name: http
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 32000
  internalPort: 32000

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  paths: []
  hosts:
    - name: mychart.local
      path: /
  tls: []

resources: {}

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

When I try to pull the image directly uasing the command below as:
`docker pull helmcr.azurecr.io/helloworldtest:0.7`
then it pulls the image successfully.

Whats can be wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I remember that I once had an issue, not related to this, but with ACR, as well. It was that the   repository: helloworldtest should have been repository: helmcr.azurecr.io/helloworldtest even tough you had it already defined in the registry.

Comment: `kubectl describe pod <podname>` may have a little bit more in the way of diagnostics.  Otherwise, it'd be helpful if you could edit the question to add the deployment spec.  Is the repository something you need to `docker login` to, and if so, is there a correct `imagePullSecret:` in the deployment spec?

Answer (score 5):

Your kubernetes cluster needs to be authenticated to the container registry to pull images, generally this is done by a docker secret:

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry regcred --docker-server=<your-registry-server> --docker-username=<your-name> --docker-password=<your-pword> --docker-email=<your-email>
```

If you are using AKS, you can grant cluster application id pull rights to the registry, that is enough.

Reading: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: Hi @4c74356b41, how can I grant cluster application id pull rights to the registry?

Comment: consult this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks

Comment: hey, did this help you? consider accepting this answer